# How to split only first page in each pdf file from directory that has muliple files?

Tags: python, pypdf

I have created two directories with input and output names. Input directory have more than one PDF file and each file has multiple pages.  I am trying to get first page of every PDF file and that should be save on output directory.
Below is the code i am tryingimport os

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

in_path = "D:/data/input/"
out_path = "D:/data/output/"

output = PdfFileWriter()
pages_to_keep = [0]

in_files = (f for f in os.listdir(in_path) if os.path.isfile(f) and f.endswith('.pdf'))



for file in in_files:
    po = open(file, 'rb')
    rd = PdfFileReader(po, strict=False)
    for i in pages_to_keep:
        page = rd.getPage(i)
        output.addPage(page)
    with open(out_path+str(file), 'wb') as f:
        output.write(f):
```

The problem is: when i executing the script that is saving  output file1 having 1 page, and output file2 having 2 pages, third file having three pages. But i need only first page from all PDF files.
How to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset output for each file:

```
for file in in_files:
    output = PdfFileWriter()  # clear output
    po = open(file, 'rb')
    rd = PdfFileReader(po, strict=False)
    for i in pages_to_keep:
        page = rd.getPage(i)
        output.addPage(page)
    with open(out_path+str(file), 'wb') as f:
        output.write(f):
```